# How to call a variable in a object Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, oop

i have 2 class:
main.m
second.m.

If i have in main.m

```
- (void)ok
{    
NSString *myString = @"OK!";
return myString;
}
```

How to call myString or "-(void) ok" function from second.m?
Thanks.

Comment: That should return an (NSString *)

Comment: First off your voiding your return. Think you should start with some basic tutorials first

Comment: -(NSString*)ok
{
   NSString* myString = @"OK!";
   return myString;
}

Answer (score 7):

somewhere in second.m and assuming main.h/m defines a "Main" class

```
Main *m = [[Main alloc] init];
NSString *mString = [m ok];
//Do Stuff
[m release];
```

However, based on the fact that your example returns void and not `NSString`, I think you have some basic knowledge to gain first. I'm guessing you don't understand Interfaces and Implementations yet, etc.

I would suggest starting with a good basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

create an instance of main.m in second.m, then then using the created instance you can easily access its own variable. i support MaskPowell's answer.